# Is there voice changing software which can make my voice sound the way that I hear it myself through bone conduction?

Tags: audio, audio-editing, voice-recording

Searching for this very specific function in voice changing or audio editing software is very difficult, and it could be that it doesn’t exist all in one feature, but instead requires a combination of pitch changing and other sorts of modulation to mimic the effect. I’m looking for software which can achieve this effect by the simplest means possible, hopefully while processing the audio live.

Comment: There is no pitch-change component. It is all EQ & resonance. Otherwise if you sang a tune, it would be in a different key in your head compared to out loud… which would be more than weird.

Comment: @Tetsujin weird, because whenever I listen to my voice recorded compared to when I hear myself talking, it sounds less deep, or younger.

Comment: It's resonance & formants, think about the 'singing a tune' & ask yourself just how stunningly weird that would be ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin I mean it makes total sense I agree with you, I’m just wondering how my voice can sound younger or older without sounding higher or lower pitched

Comment: There's really quite a complex interplay going on. In effect you're hearing two sound sources, one external, one internal. There's phase discrepancy/Haas effect due to transmission timings, resonance changes & also what, for pretty much anything other than your own voice, is a physical impossibility - sound coming from *actually inside your own head.* I don't have the math to describe it in better detail.

Comment: Voicemod ;) its a wonderful program! I recommend the full version! You can make custom voices! For replicating bone conduction, i recommend boosting the lower frequencies!